# Deleting a stored procedure in the database

Tags: sql-server

When checking for temptables (and then deleting them), I'm using a similar format to this:

```
if object_id('my_sp', 'U') is not null drop procedure my_sp
go

create procedure dbo.my_sp (
    @query varchar(100)
  , @result varchar(100) 
) as
insert into [TABLE] (finished, query, result) 
values (getdate(), @query, @result)
go
```

Looking at the examples on MSDN, this approach should work. However, it doesn't:

`There is already an object named 'my_sp' in the database.`

An alternative approach would be something like

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(my_sp)
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
WHERE
    definition LIKE '%' + 'mySP' + '%'
```

But then the question remains: why does the first approach work for (temp)tables but not for sp objects? (I like to keep things consistent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `U` in `object_id('my_sp', 'U')` specifies the name is a *user table*, use `P` for a procedure: `object_id('my_sp', 'P')`